# Excel document to create outlook tasks

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am not familiar with VBA at all. Someone at work created an excel document that has a button to push information to outlook reminders. I would love to convert it to push it to outlook tasks or create a whole new file but do not know what needs to be done. Is anyone able to help?

I beleive this is the current code that is being used.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim blnCreated As Boolean
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim CalFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application

    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
         blnCreated = True
        Err.Clear
    Else
        blnCreated = False
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set CalFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    i = 12
    Do Until Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = ""

    Set olAppt = CalFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    With olAppt

        .Start = Cells(i, 5) + Cells(i, 6)
        .End = Cells(i, 5) + (Cells(i, 6) + TimeSerial(0, 30, 0))
        .Subject = Cells(i, 1)
        .Location = Cells(i, 2)
        .Body = Cells(i, 3)
        .BusyStatus = olBusy
        .ReminderSet = False
        .Save

    End With

        i = i + 1
        Loop
    Set olAppt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "The items have been exported to your Outlook Calendar"

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred while exporting to your Outlook Calendar"

End Sub
```

[image: outlook spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

open the VBA editor, and paste that code into a module or ThisWorkBook

add a reference to the Microsoft Outlook Object Library (Tools, References...). This is required for Excel to interact with Outlook (create mail and appointment items, etc.)

add a button to run the procedure (I am assuming you have the Developer tab shown on the ribbon. Click that, Insert, select a form controls button, place it on the worksheet. Right-click and click Assign Macro. Choose your macro from the list. Click Ok.

Then, clicking the button will run the procedure.

It worked for me, but only after commenting out the lines referring to ranges on the spreadsheet (which I did not have). Also, for the appointment properties (start, end, body, etc.) I gave them some made-up dates and info just to make it happy.